# QT nightmare with 2 simultaneous database connections

Tags: c++, database, qt

I need to read from a microsoft **ODBC** database and a **postgres** database **at the same time** in my QT code.

**Problems**

1. Once i open up the database connections, how do i instruct qsqlQuery which one to use?

   why are my database connections failing yet these databases exist

Thanks

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <Qdebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //odbc
    QSqlDatabase dbODBC= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","microsoft_connection");
    dbODBC.setDatabaseName("BIO");
    if(!dbODBC.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"failed to open BIO";
        exit(1);
    }
    //postgress
    QSqlDatabase dbPostgres= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL","postgres_connection");
    dbPostgres.setDatabaseName("makerere_boys_db");
    dbPostgres.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    dbPostgres.setUserName("postgres");
    dbPostgres.setPassword("student");  
    if (!dbPostgres.open()) {
        qDebug()<<"failed to open postgres database";
        exit(1);
    }
    //how do i tell QSqlQuery to use dbODBC instead of dbPostgress?. Frustration follows
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT * FROM fees");
    qDebug()<<query.value(0).toString();
    return a.exec();
    system("pause");
}
```

The above code compiles but QSqlQuery says database is not open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, you are using [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2) ctor for your query object, and just using the default arguments for both parameters. Notice what the docs say. You are therefore telling the ctor to use the default database, which must be the postgres one for you.

Answer (score 3):

For issue #1: You need to pass the database in as an argument to the QSqlQuery constructor:

```
QSqlQuery query(dbPostgres);
...
```

For issue #2: Look at the documentation for the QSqlDatabase class. At the bottom of the function description for `addDatabase` it states:

> Before using the connection, it must be initialized. e.g., call some
>   or all of setDatabaseName(), setUserName(), setPassword(),
>   setHostName(), setPort(), and setConnectOptions(), and, finally,
>   open().

Looks like you are only calling setDatabaseName. You may need to provide the object with the additional information described.

Answer (score 1):

```
QSqlQuery query1(QSqlDatabase::database("postgres_connection"));
query1.exec("SELECT * FROM fees");
while (query1.next()){
    QString col0 = query1.value(0).toString();
    QString col1 = query1.value(1).toString();
    qDebug() <<  QString("%1 , %2").arg(col0).arg(col1);
}



QSqlQuery query2(QSqlDatabase::database("microsoft_connection"));
query2.exec("SELECT * FROM fees");    
while (query2.next()){
    QString col0 = query2.value(0).toString();
    QString col1 = query2.value(1).toString();
    qDebug() <<  QString("%1 , %2").arg(col0).arg(col1);
}
```

Kinda off-topic, but you don't really need to instantiate a `QCoreApplication` (or `QApplication`) to run queries against a RDBMS. You can safely comment out

```
// this line
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
// and this line
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
// and this line
return a.exec();
```